# ReduceRegion(s) Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to find the area of a classified land cover across the study area using the Google Earth Engine's Python API. I am trying to do this by mapping a `.reduceRegion` function across the image collection using the approach below.

```
# Salt marsh extents are images where pixels = 1 if salt marsh has been detected

salt_marsh_area = salt_marsh_extents.map(lambda image:
                                      image.reduceRegion(
                                          reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(),
                                          geometry=whole_estuary.geometry(),
                                          scale=30
                                      ))
```

However, when I try and export this to my Google Drive or use a `.getInfo()` to inspect the result I get an error of `ee.ee_exception.EEException: Collection.map: A mapped algorithm must return a Feature or Image.`

How do you convert this into a table format for export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.reduceRegion()` returns an `ee.Dict`. You can use this, wrap it into an `ee.Feature` without setting a geometry and return that feature. In the end you can export this Feature Collection as a CSV to get a table with your values. This is how you would do it:

```py
def reduce_salt(image):
  reduced = image.reduceRegion(
              reducer=ee.Reducer.sum(),
              geometry=whole_estuary.geometry(),
              scale=30)
  return ee.Featue(None, reduced)

salt_marsh_area = salt_marsh_extents.map(reduce_salt)

task = ee.batch.Export.table.toDrive(
  collection=salt_marsh_area,
  description='reduced',
  fileFormat='CSV'
);

task.start()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I've just given it a try and it works perfectly. I'm just curious, what is the role of the None statement here?

Comment: The first argument given to an `ee.Feature` is the geometry. So you could also give it `whole_estuary.geometry()` instead of `None`. With `None` it simply doesn't get a geometry, it only gets the properties. In Python you could probably also skip the `None` altogether and supply it with a keyword, like this `ee.Feature(properties=reduced)`